# Debian server "su root" weird behaviour

Tags: linux, debian

My Debian server is recently acting strangely. I have a colored bash every time I connect to the server with the root user. However when I enter:

```
su root
```

the terminal isn't colored anymore. In addition when I create a new screen after I entered `su root` and I reconnect to the server, it just disappears.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

Comment: When you connect using another user and then su to root, does the other user have a colored terminal? My guess is that there's something in the `.bashrc` file that's removing the colors.

Comment: Well I don't really care that much about the colors but rather that if I want to launch a screen with a node application using a npm plugin, that it doesn't work (I can't see the screen when I log in manually).

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. While I'm not sure how to help with the screen issue, perhaps you can take a look at `PM2` for running Node applications without having to keep them open in the terminal. It's a sort of process manager that automatically monitors Node applications and starts them when they're down.

Comment: I'm planning to use PM2 in production but for develpoment I need a way to see the console of a node instance in real time, and so far I have not seen the ability to do that in PM2 (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I believe PM2 by default logs output to a logfile. I guess you could tail that file to get a kinda realtime output.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Still it doesn't work. I see a error message now: "pm2 command not found". I don't get it, it's the same user as I use the terminal...

Comment: Okay I have added the node/bin directory to /etc/environment and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve the PM2 issue, or the issue you originally stated in the question? If it's the original question, you may want to submit an answer so people can easily find the answer if they every have a similar issue.